# App Video Preview link to itunesconnect

Tags: app-store-connect, itunes

Can we post app video preview link in the itunesconnect app description section.

Comment: No, you can't. But you can add video directly into itunesconnect.

Answer (score 0):

There's no definite exclusion in the App Review Guidelines concerning links in the description part of your app. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#metadata

But any links in your description will just show up as "text" and are not "clickable" for your users. They would have to manually type the URL into their browser. (It's not possible to copy & paste text from the App Store description)

As jacky suggested, you should upload an App Preview, which will appear "before" your screenshots. Apple put a nice page together, what is allow for App Previews: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/

On a side note: You still can create a landing page for your app including the video and add that URL to the "Marketing URL field" in iTunes Connect.